# business layer code outside of Controllers folder gives compilation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've read in other posts that you can put the business logic in a VS2013 MVC project "anywhere", which I take to mean "possibly outside the Controllers folder".

However, when I create an App_Code folder in my project, and put business logic classes in it, (with the build property set to Compile, not Content) I get a compilation error, on the following, and the code editor intellisense won't recognize the the .Caching in the following:

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;
```

If I move the class back into a subfolder of Controllers, no problem, the .Caching appears in intellisense and no compilation error occurs.

Any explanations of why this might be so, and how I might adjust my project to allow business logic classes to operate correctly outside the Controllers folder, would be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably specifically the App_Code folder - this folder is treated differently during compilation. Does it work if you put the business logic elsewhere?

Comment: @Sam, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that manana and post back.

Comment: yep, that was it; the full answer is in Brenda Green's post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App_Code folder contains code that is compiled at **runtime**.

See the following reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx

If you have business logic, it's probably best to put it into an external (from the webiste) library to increase reuse and enable better compartmentalization.

Comment: great link, has a sub link that is very explicit about how App_Code has special meaning in ASP.NET and what it will and won't do.  Very helpful to get that spelled out.

Comment: here is that sub-link,very explicit http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html

Answer (score 1):

Add a business layer class library project to your solution, and then add reference to this business layer class library project to your MVC project.

Answer (score 1):

First off, there's no such ting as `App_Code` folder for MVC.

**Why?**

Well, the `App_Code` concept is meant to work with ***Website Projects***, however, MVC are ***Web Application Projects*** which is a framework or implementation of a pattern to work closer to the HTTP protocol and web requests and separate concerns into presentation (views), request handlers (controllers) and models. So, don't expect it to work with `App_Code`

**Suggestion**

Create/Add a ***Class Library*** project in the same VS Solution where you can keep all your business logic and then reference this project in your MVC app

Comment: What do Web Application projects have to do with working closer to the HTTP protocol? They are the original project type for ASP.NET.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned nothing and I haven't even implied such thing...I'm simply answering why the App_Code does NOT work in and MVC project

Comment: "MVC are Web Application Projects which is a framework or implementation of a pattern to work closer to the HTTP protocol". I think you ran two ideas together.

Comment: @JohnSaunders and what I think is that it depends on how you want to read it and in my opinion, there's only ONE way to read it..."MVC...which is", instead of "...Web Application Projects which IS...". Obviously, it's not proper english if you take everything out of context

Comment: There is such a thing - App_Code will work (dynamically compile) in MVC projects, but it's not common and has limited usefulness (shared Razor helpers being one of the few benefits).

Comment: @Sam I don't understand what you mean by "it's not common and has limited usefulness"...can you be more clear about this? Are you saying that if I add an App_Code folder to an MVC project I can simply dump code files and expect it to work out-of-the-box? Because as far as I know Microsoft has been pretty clear the Web Application Projects do not support the App_Code concept...this is way before MVC was born. That you can customize the project is another story, it's like adding a Script controller to an MVC project or a Controllers folder to a WebForms app, isn't it?

Comment: @Leo yes, that's exactly what I mean. cs files in App_Code will dynamically compile even if used in a Web Application project.

Comment: @Sam seriously, you are VERY confused...by default, MVC projects are WAP, NOT web site projects. By default, Web Application Projects do NOT support dynamic compilation. I don't understand your argument, it's 150% wrong. You will need to use a different build provider or a custom one and that is something I will NOT suggest anyone to do just for the sake of being able to use the App_Code folder...it's ridiculous

Comment: @Leo I'm impressed, I've never been 150% wrong before. I've just done a test MVC5 project and it definitely works (using IIS Express). If you think about it, how would ASP.NET know what type of project was used to create the web application?

Comment: @Sam I have not implied that ASP.NET is NOT project agnostic. All I'm saying is that dynamic compilation is not supported. Why? WAPs are compiled into a single binary and whatever changes you make in any code file in the App_Code folder will NOT affect already-compiled binaries. If you have any references to the App_Code objects in your views, it'll work, but Controllers will not know about this change. That's why I initially asked you what was the nature of your comment because it doesn't seem to fit with this question

Comment: @Leo All I meant was that the statement "there's no such ting as App_Code folder for MVC" was not correct. You generally wouldn't use App_Code in an MVC project, but it will dynamically compile if present.

Comment: @Sam if the App_Code concept exists for MVC...why can't I reference my business logic objects created under the App_Code folder from any controller? Why do I get compilation errors? You claimed you got it working. Can you shed some light? How did you do it?

Comment: @Leo there are a couple of ways to accomplish this. Contact me via email (sam@<mydomain>) if you’re interested in taking the conversation further.

Comment: @Sam it's ok mate. I know there are ways to accomplish this but as I said in previous comments it is something that I would never recommend just for the sake of using the App_Code concept in WAPs. In my opinion, if something that's no supported takes too much effort to achieve very little, then it is a hack...especially when there are better and neater ways to achieve the same. My argument is not about what can be accomplished or not, it's about native support for features